# Proper way of getting several scripts asynchronously using Jquery with post-document-ready callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous

I'm planning on getting several JS files from my server asynchronously while the page loads. I am aware of the Jquery function "getScript", but this only gets 1 script. Is there any way of specifying a callback to be executed when a batch of scripts have been fetched from the server?

I thought about doing something like this:

```
$.getScript(script1, function() {
$.getScript(script2, function() {
$.getScript(script3, function() {
...
...
});});....});
```

But this loads the scripts in sequence, and I'd like the requests to be done in parallel.

As a more general question which supersedes this one, what is the best way of loading N resources (CSS, images, scripts, etc) asynchronously specifying a single callback to be executed when all the resources have been loaded?

Update: In addition to this, I need the callback to be executed after the document is ready (signaled by the $(document).ready event). Any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to call `getScript` 3 times in a row, passing a callback which increments a counter and calls the real callback if the counter is `3`.

You can make a simple wrapper function to do this:

```
function getScripts(names, callback) {
    var received = 0;
    var realCallback = function() { 
        received++;
        if (received === names.length)
            $(callback);
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++)
        $.getScript(names[i], realCallback);
}
```

(Edited to call the callback when the document is ready)

You can call it like this:

```
getScripts([ "script1", "script2", "script3" ], function() { ... });
```

Comment: This can be simplified by removing the counter, using `names.pop` (or `names.shift`) and checking to see if the length of the array is 0, rather than keeping track of the counter.

Comment: @Ryan: That will be a little bit simpler, but (minutely) slower.  Also, it means that the caller cannot reuse the array.  (Which is unlikely anyway)

Comment: This looks great, nice use of closures :)
I'm facing a somehow related problem. I'd need to be able to determine which of the callback and $(document).ready are executed first. The thing is I need to execute code only when all the scripts have loaded (and executed) and the DOM has been completely parsed. I'll update the question to reflect this.

Comment: @Diego: Then you would change: `callback();` to `$(document).ready(callback);`

Comment: What happens if $(document).ready was executed before execution reaches that callback() line in the realCallback function? The callback wouldn't execute right?

Comment: @Diego: I am pretty sure that if the document is already loaded, the callback will be executed immediately.

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize a `counter` variable with number of resources to be fetched.
2. Use the same callback for each asynchronous operation.
3. This callback should decrease `counter` and check it's value. Once it gets to zero, it should invoke the code to be triggered on completion.

Answer (score 0):

```
var _couter=0;
var _calledScripts=0;
function _loadScripts(arrayOfScripts,_callBackFunction)
{
   _counter=arrayOfScripts.length;
   _calledScripts=0;
    jQuery.each(arrayOfScripts,function(index,item){
            jQuery.getScript(item, function(){
                _calledScripts++;
                if(_calledScripts==_couter)
                 {
                     _callBackFunction() 
                 }
             });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [async.js](http://caolanmcmahon.com/async.html) to do this stuff:

```
async.map(scripts, $.getScript, function () {
    // called after all have completed...
});
```